# C++ Memory management failing when deleting Bitmap and CLSID objects using GDI+

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, bitmap, gdi+

I am unable to manage memory for Bitmap and CLSID objects I have created in a screenshot object class. Both of these are from the GDI+ library. The header lists the following private variables in Screenshot.h

```
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"
#pragma once
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")


using namespace std;
using namespace Gdiplus;


class Screenshot
{
private:
    HDC dc, memdc, fontdc;
    HBITMAP membit;
    Bitmap* bmpPtr;
    CLSID clsid;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid);

public:
    Screenshot();
    ~Screenshot();
    void TakeScreenshot(string userAction, string winName, long xMousePos, long yMousePos, long long tStamp);
    void SaveScreenshot(string filename);
    void memoryManagement();
};
```

Then when my main program takes a screenshot, the values are filled in with TakeScreenshot(), but not yet saved to disk

```
void Screenshot::TakeScreenshot(//redacted for readibility) {
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    dc = ::GetDC(0);
    int scaleHeight, scaleWidth = 0;        
    int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
    scaleHeight = Height + (0.1 * Height);
    memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
    membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, Width, scaleHeight);
    HBITMAP bmpContainer = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, membit);
    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    //Other code that adds fonts, etc. Does not invoke bmpPtr

    bmpPtr = new Bitmap(membit, NULL);
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
```

If the screenshot is saved, another function SaveScreenshot() uses bmpPtr->Save() and Gdiplus shutdown is called inside of it. However, some of the screenshots get popped off from a queue (STL queue) and out of memory instead of saved, as follows:

```
void ManageQueue(Screenshot& ssObj)
{
    //If queue contains 30 screenshots, pop off first element and push new object
    //Else just push new object
    if (screenshotQueue.size() == MAX_SCREENSHOTS)
    {
        screenshotQueue.front().memoryManagement();
        screenshotQueue.pop();
        screenshotQueue.push(ssObj);
    }
    else
    {
        screenshotQueue.push(ssObj);
    }
}
```

I wrote a MemoryManagement() function to perform the necessary releases and deletes before the Screenshot is popped off. This function is not called if the screenshot has been saved:

```
void Screenshot::memoryManagement()
{
    delete bmpPtr;
    delete &clsid;
    ReleaseDC(NULL, memdc);
    DeleteObject(fontdc);  
    DeleteObject(memdc);
    DeleteObject(membit);
}
```

When either the delete on bmpPtr or clsid is called, whether it is from this function or in the deconstructor, the program is crashing. I am experiencing significant memory leaks with the program now and without running a windows equivalent of Valgrind I'm assuming it's coming from here. How can I successfully delete these objects? I will credit any answer in my source code as a contributing programmer. Please leave any suggestions for improving my question if needed.

Comment: Using the address-of operator `&` in a `delete` is a big red flag. Only `delete` what you actually `new` (and `delete[]` what you `new[]`).

Comment: I may be able to get away with not deleting the clsids, but the bitmaps definitely need to go. Removing delete &clsid entirely still causes a crash at delete bmpPtr.

Comment: Maybe you should show the constructor and destructor for `Bitmap` then.  Add logging to your program or step through it in a debugger to ensure the pointer value of `bmpPtr` being deleted is the same as the one you allocated.  The problem could also be elsewhere, depending on whether these are member variables in the `Screenshot` class or not (you were not clear about that), and how the `Screenshot` class is constructed, destructed, copied, or generally otherwise used.

Comment: Well you do `bmpPtr = new Bitmap(membit, NULL);` so of course you should do `delete bmpPtr`. If that crashes then the problem is most likely in the `Bitmap` class (which you do not show us), but could also be because you have some reassignment to `bmpPtr` that you don't show us or because you `delete bmpPtr` multiple times?

Comment: Clarifications: Bitmap, HDC, etc. are part of the Gdi+ library, not a class I wrote or part of `Screenshot` . According to MSDN, new Bitmaps allocated using the `Bitmap` constructor stay in memory "until the Bitmap::Bitmap object is deleted or goes out of scope." bmpPtr is only used in the code I have displayed above. `Screenshot` only uses default constructor and destructor at the moment.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: By the way, do you pass `Screenshot` objects by value, or return objects by value? Then do you implement [the rules of three, five or zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?  If so, run a debug build in the debugger, then check the output window after you quit your program.  It will usually tell you _exactly_ where your leaked memory was allocated.

Comment: Yes I just finished running the debugger, it's coming from bmpPtr.

Comment: You should _not_ be calling `GdiplusStartup` inside your `TakeScreenshot` function.  Nor should you be calling `GdiplusShutdown` anywhere in your class either.  Call the startup _once_ before you do anything with GDI, and call shutdown _once_ after you are completely finished with everything GDI-related.  Usually this is done at the beginning and end of your program respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to use the namespace delete instead of regular delete. Switching to this prevented the break point trigger during debug and has sealed the memory leak.

```
    void Screenshot::memoryManagement()
{
    ::delete bmpPtr;
    ReleaseDC(NULL, memdc);
    DeleteObject(fontdc);
    DeleteObject(memdc);
    DeleteObject(membit);
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

Comment: It should be `ReleaseDC(NULL, dc)` to avoid resource leak. `bmpPtr` is storing the screenshot bitmap independently of other handles, you don't need to keep the other handles. You may hold `memdc`, `membit`... and reuse them but `dc` should be released as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> scaleHeight = Height + (0.1 * Height);
> ```

This seems to be an attempt to fix the problem with DPI scaling. It will work if DPI settings is at 10%, but that's usually not the case. You have to make your program DPI aware through the manifest file. Use `SetProcessDPIAware` for a quick fix.

Don't declare `dc`, `memdc`, etc. as class members. These are GDI handles (not GDI+) which you can hold for a short time, usually during the duration of the function. You have to release them as soon as possible.

Also other variables like `clsid` don't need to be declared as class members. You can declare them as class member if you wish, but there is nothing to gain.

If you have a multi-monitor setup you also need `SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN/Y` to get the top-left corner of the monitor setup.

```
//call this once on start up
SetProcessDPIAware();

HDC dc = ::GetDC(0);
int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
HBITMAP membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, Width, Height);
HBITMAP bmpContainer = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, membit);
BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, dc, x, y, SRCCOPY);

Bitmap* bmpPtr = new Bitmap(membit, NULL);
// or just Bitmap bmp(membit, NULL);

CLSID clsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
bmpPtr->Save(L"output.jpg", &clsid);

//cleanup:
delete bmpPtr;
SelectObject(memdc, bmpContainer);
DeleteObject(membit);
DeleteDC(memdc);
ReleaseDC(0, dc);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the rescale is not for DPI, it's to add text at the bottom of the screenshot in a blank area. The GDI handles and CLSID are made as class members because I cannot immediately Save the screenshot. Trust me, I would love to be able to do your code snippet, but the screenshots must be held in memory for an unknown amount of time and cannot be saved immediately. The unsaved `Screenshot` object is managed by the STL Queue and popped off if more screenshots come in. I have added example code to the main question.

Comment: The screen shot can be stored independently of GDI handles and other variables. `delete &clsid;` is wrong. I would recommend reading up on C++ basic and start with easier examples.